# Querying first element with [0] not working in app but in Vision

Tags: sanity, groq

I have kind of a singleton document in Sanity that features the content of the home page. When I try to query the type `home` document with `[0]` to get the first element I always get `null` as response. However, the same query works fine in Vision.

```
export const HOME_QUERY = groq`*[_type == "home"][0]`;

export async function getHome(): Promise<Home> {
    const data = await client.fetch(HOME_QUERY);
    return data;
}
```

Trying to use the `home` content, but getting an error because `content` is null. If I remove `[0]` from my GROQ query it works fine.

```
export default async function Home() {
  const content = await getHome();

  return (
    <main className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
      <h1 className="text-4xl">{content.title}</h1>
    </main>
  );
}
```

This is my client

```
import { createClient } from "@sanity/client/stega";

import { apiVersion, dataset, projectId, useCdn } from "../env";

export const client = createClient({
  apiVersion,
  dataset,
  projectId,
  useCdn,
  // These settings will be overridden in
  // ./sanity/lib/store.ts when draftMode is enabled
  perspective: "published",
  stega: {
    enabled: false,
    studioUrl: "/cms",
  },
});
```

Query in Vision

[image]